# Correlation Matrix in R- Big Data Set

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am very new to programming and R, I am currently working with a very big data set (300 columns and 400k Rows.) Some of the columns are not in numeric form (Eg. some columns include customer id, country names, city names etc.)

I want R to ignore these columns and just give me the names of column combinations with higher than .95 or lower than -.95 correlation between them as usually such columns just create noise in ML and can be used for feature reduction.

Something like this: 
Column 1    Column 2    Correlation:
xyz          cvg         0.964
xyz          yut         0.951
yut          cvg         0.967

Let me know if you need more information. Thank you for your time.

Regards,
InWoods

Answer (score 1):

Trying to understand your problem with the available details, your basic problem seem to be the extraction of the numerical columns from your data.frame.  Take a look at `is.numeric()` function to begin.